# ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network, anomaly-detection

i am following this tutorial to implement GAN  https://github.com/krantirk/Credit-GANS/blob/master/creditcard_GANs.ipynb but i got this error can anyone help?

i got this error

```
fraud_wilcox = random.sample(list(temp_df[temp_df['Class']==1][feat]), k=30)
  File "C:\Users\user11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\random.py", line 318, in sample
    raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
```

e

Answer (score 3):

`random.sample(population, k)` is used for sampling the population **without replacement**, the error thus means that the number of samples is bigger than the population.

What you actually want to use is `random.choices(population, k=1)` for sampling **with replacement**.

So your code should be

```py
fraud_wilcox = random.choices(list(temp_df[temp_df['Class']==1][feat]), k=30)
```